# Call REST API Client from another API with JWT token

Tags: .net-core

I have a platform with two API's. Let's call them API A and API B. I have a case, that i have to call API B from API A and both need a singned user. So i added there Policies and JWT token.

Of course, Policies are the same in both APIs.

So, using swagger i am calling Method A in API A, with authorized Token. Method is working correctly and calling Method B from API B, but HTTP client hasn't got token, because is not filling anywhere..

I am trying to fill in a Startup.cs in API A, a httpClient to using the token, but i dont know, how to get HttpContext with the token.

This is how i am trying to fill the token in the HttpClient, but i dont exactly now, how i should get the token from the context.

```
services.AddHttpClient("Api_B_Client", x =>
        {
            x.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new System.Net.Http.Headers.AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", "");
        });
```

In the context token exists, because i am parsing like this:

```
services.AddAuthentication().AddJwtBearer(cfg =>
        {
            SetupJwtBearerWithDecryption(cfg);
        });
```

In the SetupJwtBearerWithDecryption method i have an OnMessageReceived event and there i am parsing the token

Comment: You can read it from Request.header in api b

Answer (score 0):

My solution for the problem is to get from Configuration HttpContextAccessor and the object has authorization token which i was looking for

```
services.TryAddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();

        services.AddHttpClient("client", x =>
        {
            var context = Configuration.Get<HttpContextAccessor>();
            x.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = 
                new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", context.HttpContext.Request.Headers["Authorization"]);
        });
```